# Animates UVIew in UICollectionViewCell doesn't work

Tags: swift

I have a collectioviewcell that hold a view that contains two buttons this view that always all hide, this view trigger to isHidden= false  to  show view and choose between two options. I trigger an animation to hide the view when the user tap a Button, but the animation doesn't happen the view is hide immediately without delay, below I share the code used in UICollectionViewCell

```
func showView() {
        myView.isHidden = false
        myView.alpha = 0.0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.myView.alpha = 1.0
          }
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.myView.alpha = 1.0
             }
}


func hideView() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, delay: 5.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                           self.myView.alpha = 0.0
                       }) { (finished) in
                           self.myView.isHidden = true
                      }
   }
```

I tried to use layoutSubviews() and the animation does not happen

```
func hideView() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, delay: 5.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                           self.myView.alpha = 0.0
                       }) { (finished) in
                           self.myView.isHidden = true
                            self.myView.layoutSubviews()
                      }
   }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.